# BootStrap Layout height 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting to look into bootstrap to make a layout for an app.
I'm trying to make the  left bar full height with the screen, making this the  content will need to follow also.

I already try the height: 100% but's it's not working.

I place my code in JSFiddle please check, i really apreciate your help

`[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/fhavio/448qcxg6/)`

Comment: did you try a clearfix, or is it more complex than that?

Comment: Try something like this: http://codeply.com/go/1egwlFgOrD You should make the sidebar fixed so that scrolling the main content area allows it to remain 100% height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the left bar out of your `.row`, make it 100% high, and also give `html` and `body` `height: 100%;

https://jsfiddle.net/umb1kwp2/1/

Answer (score 0):

These units are vh (viewport height), vw (viewport width), vmin (viewport minimum length) and vmax (viewport maximum length).

```
 style="height:100vh;"
```

For more details click [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css like that
     #leftBar { height: 100vh; }